# Emit signal by clicking on the part of the text in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-signals, emit

I have an abstract in `Text` item and I need to emit the signal when I click on some phrase in this text:

```
Text {
    id: textFirst
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    width: parent.width
    text: qsTr("Some long part of text and I need to emit signal by clicking on THIS")
    font.pointSize: 14
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
}
```

So, the signal should be emitted when I click on "THIS". The window, where this `Text` located on is resizable, so I can't calculate the location of "THIS" beforehand. So, does it possible to do it?

PS I found that it possible to add hyperlinks, but emitting signals is a bit different

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Put the Text into Rich Text mode and use a hyperlink like this:

```
Text {
    id: textFirst
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    text: qsTr("Some long part of text and I need to emit signal by clicking on <a href='app://goto_this'>THIS</a>")
    font.pointSize: 14
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap

    onLinkActivated: {
        console.log("link", link);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MouseArea

```
Text {
    id: textFirst
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    width: parent.width
    text: qsTr("Some long part of text and I need to emit signal by clicking on THIS")
    font.pointSize: 14
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: SIGNAL()
    }
}
```

But figure out how you can stop sending signal for other text.

Suggestion: Use HTML to display you text and have THIS as hyperlink. And in mousearea use `acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton` to skip click on text but does call `onClicked` when clicked on hyperlink.